# Leaving group chat in Telegram Messenger on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, group

[Telegram Messenger](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/telegram-messenger/id686449807?mt=8) on my iPhone has no chat group's **exit button**, like the existing *"Leave chat"* on Android version.

Could anyone please tell me **where** is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-leave-a-group-on-telegram

Comment: No, @NoahL . Thanks you, but there is no `three white dots on the top right` on the screen inside my chat.

Comment: Nope, its not leaving the group (slide left) its just deleting the chats. Meanwhile when u see in data storage under settings option the data keep increasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my iPhone **iOS v9.3.5** the method requires **sliding left** the desired chat:

[image: Sliding left from chats screen]

Then you will have the **delete** option ("Eliminar", my device is in spanish, sorry) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following steps apply for Telegram for iOS. I am using iOS 10.3.1

1. tap the **group** in your chat overview
2. tap the **group's nam**e on the top
3. a menu slides down. Tap **info**
4. You will see all members in the group. **Scroll down**.
5. On the bottom tap **delete and exit**

[image: step 1]

[image: step 3]

[image: step 4]

[image: step 5]

Comment: Step 5 is not possible: there is no **delete and exit** button or option at all on the top bottom.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez I have added screenshots to my answer.

Comment: Still no such `Delete and Exit`. I have added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an iPhone 7 and when I tap leave, it automaticaaly exited me from the supergroup. Leave on iphone is equal to leave and exit on android

Comment: The question was about "Where is the button to exit/leave/out (or whatever is called) button". This is a possible valid answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281076/84935 .